# How do you organize your variable declarations?

Tags: vba

I want to hear how others go about this, and why, to see if there is a better method that what I do.

Do you do this:

```
dim x as long
dim y as long
dim a as string
dim b as integer
dim c as integer
dim d as integer
```

or this:

```
dim x as long, y
dim a as string
dim b as integer, c, d
```

or do you declare them as they are needed within the script? or something else?

I have a few scripts that have 60+ variables, and how to organize them is something I always question

thanks!

Comment: There is no real "correct" way - really a matter of personal preference.  I put mine at the top of the method (all jumbled together), but I also see them declared just before being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim x as long, y as long
dim a as string
dim b as integer, c as integer, d as integer
```

You have to specify the type of each variable, otherwise it will be a variant.
Don't forget to set the VBE option to automatically insert `OPtion explicit` at the top of each module. It will save you time and sweat.

A common practice is to have all your DIMs at the top of the module/function/sub

Comment: Historically that may have been true.  For VBA, the current thinking is to declare variables just before they are first used so as to avoid the 'wall of declarations'.  It also makes cutting and pasting code somewhat less prone to errors due to declarations or other sinle assignment lines being missed out.